# IllegalMonitorStateException при использовании Guava StripedLock

Tags: java

Словил вышеуказанное исключение в следующем куске кода при вызове `releaseLock()` при нагрузочном тестировании:

```
public void addReference(Path path) {
    acquireLock(path);
    try {
        AtomicInteger counter = references.get(path);
        if (counter == null) {
            counter = new AtomicInteger();
            references.put(path, counter);
        }
        int value = counter.incrementAndGet();
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Currently holding {} references for path {}", value, path);
        }
    } finally {
        releaseLock(path);
    }
}
```

за `acquireLock()` и `releaseLock()` прячутся вызовы к WriteLock, получаемому из StripedLock гугловой Guava.

Как такое может быть? Пока данная проблема проявлялась единожды, но все равно не хотелось бы оставлять ее за бортом.

Comment: Не прячьте вызовы, покажите весь код. И стектрейс тоже.

Comment: @Roman `locks.get(id).writeLock().lock();` и `locks.get(id).writeLock().unlock();`, как бы неожиданно это не звучало

Comment: А что за класс `Path` - это какой-то ваш или `java.nio.file.Path`? И каково преобразование `path` -> `id`?

Comment: @Roman nio.file.Path. Никакого преобразования, просто переменная так называется.

Comment: Полный стектрейс дайте пожалуйста.

Comment: @a_gura боюсь, уже не смогу. Но ничего неожиданного там не было, могу кинуть исключение после `releaseLock()`, и он будет выглядеть идентично. Повторюсь, такое поведение обнаружилось один раз на десятки тысяч вызовов.